# How to fix search functionality in mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My search function is not working. when I run the application it will display records fine

after enter an input in search box it displays all records no filtering

This used to work before I Implemented my viewModel

My View

```
@model WTCoro2.Models.PersonViewModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "People";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "People", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <b>Search By:</b>
    @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Name", true) <text>Name</text>
    @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Title") <text>Title</text>
   // @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Salary") <text>Salary</text>

    <br />
    @Html.TextBox("BusinessEntityID") <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            JobTitle
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.pers.First().FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.pers.First().LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            Email Address
        </th>
        <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.phn.First().PhoneNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.pers.First().BusinessEntity.BusinessEntityID)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @if (Model.pers.Count() == 0)
    {
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">No Record Found</td>
        </tr>
    }
    else
    {

        foreach (var item in Model.pers)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee.JobTitle)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailAddresses.First().EmailAddress1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PersonPhones.First().PhoneNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BusinessEntity.BusinessEntityID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.BusinessEntityID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.BusinessEntityID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.BusinessEntityID })
            </td>

        </tr>
        }
    }

</table>
```

My search inside my controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, string currentFilter, int? page, string searchBy, string startdate = null, string enddate = null)
        {
            var mymodel = new PersonViewModel();
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            var people_list = mymodel.pers = db.People.ToList();
            var employee_list = mymodel.emp = db.Employees.ToList();
            var history_list = mymodel.history = db.EmployeeDepartmentHistories.ToList();
            var email_list = mymodel.emldrs = db.EmailAddresses.ToList();
            var phone_list = mymodel.phn = db.PersonPhones.ToList();
            /* if (searchString != null)
             {
                 page = 1;
             }
             else
             {
                 searchString = currentFilter;
             }
             ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;*/
            searchString = "";
            if (searchBy == "Title")
            {
                mymodel.emp = (employee_list.Where(x => x.JobTitle == searchString || searchString == null).ToList());
                return View(mymodel);
            }
            /*  else if (startdate != null && enddate != null)
              {
                  DateTime start = DateManager.GetDate(startdate) ?? DateTime.Now;
                  DateTime end = DateManager.GetDate(enddate) ?? DateTime.Now;
                  return View(history_list.Where(x => x.StartDate >= start && x.EndDate <= end).ToList());

              }*/
            else
            {
                mymodel.pers = (people_list.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(searchString) || x.LastName.StartsWith(searchString) || searchString == null).ToList());
                return View(mymodel);
            }

        }
```

I expect the search filter records but it just does nothing

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a lot of code for us to have to grok in order to help you out. Can you use debugging to narrow down the scope of the problem? For example, what are the form values getting sent by the browser? Are those getting correctly converted into arguments to your Index method (e.g. is `searchString` null? Can you be more descriptive when you say it "does nothing"?

Comment: sorry for the lot of code. we I say it does nothing I mean the page just refreshes without the filtering being done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove

```
searchString = "";
```

As this line is resetting whatever value you pass into the controller to be empty. Then change the signature of your controller to

```
 public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString = "", string currentFilter, int? page, string searchBy, string startdate = null, string enddate = null)
```

which will assign searchString a default value of "" if it's null.

Comment: This worked thanks but now it filters only by name and it doesn't work when I try to filter by Title, it just returns all records again

Comment: Try to debug it and see what value you get in the searchBy parameter of your controller when searching by Title @kgosi.itachi

Comment: I found the issue. It filters it just doesn't but the filtered records go at the bottom of the list so you don't see it unless you go right at the bottom of the records

Answer (score 1):

You've set:

```
        searchString = "";
```

So your employees are either going to get filtered down to those whose JobTitle is "", or those whose FirstName or LastName start with "" (every string starts with "").

Comment: Thanks for replying. When I remove that line I get a "System.ArgumentNullException: value cannot be null"

Comment: @kgosi.itachi: That implies that `searchString` is null at this point. I notice your form doesn't have any inputs named "searchString". Were you expecting `searchString` to have a value? Where did you expect that value to come from? What behavior did you expect to have when `searchString` doesn't have a value? Have you learned how to step through your code and inspect variables in a debugger to understand what's happening at runtime?